# /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules:1 Invalid operator for GROUP. found in Error logs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, udev

I found this error listed as important in my Ubuntu 20.04 Logs application and wanted to know if its something I need to worry about or not. Can someone point me to some information about this or just let me know if this is something to worry about?

Comment: `cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules` please.

Comment: Result: KERNEL=="kfd", GROUP=="video", MODE="0660"

Comment: I have no Idea from where this udev.rule came from. If `dpkg -S /etc/udev/rules.d70-amdgpu.rules` no package find, when `sudo mv /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules /etc/udev/rules.d/70-amdgpu.rules.bak`  the rule is ignored by your system, because of the error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just want to clarify; If I run `dpkg -S /etc/udev/rules.d70-amdgpu.rules` and I don't find any packages, then I should go ahead and run the move command?

Comment: Yes it only renames the file

Answer (score 4):

You have one equal sign too many: it should be `GROUP="video"`, not `GROUP=="video"`.